# How do I handle errors so a locked table will unlock in a procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I want to have a stored procedure that does the following:

1. Locks a table
2. Checks for a value in it
3. Updates same table based on that value
4. Unlocks the table

If an error occurs between 1 and 4, will the table be unlocked? Or do I need to capture the error somehow? (how?)

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't lock a table within a stored procedure in MySQL.

> SQL Statements Not Permitted in Stored Routines
>
> Stored routines cannot contain arbitrary SQL statements. The following statements are not permitted:
>
> The locking statements `LOCK TABLES` and `UNLOCK TABLES`.
>
> <sup>— http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html</sup>

If you are using InnoDB, then you can accomplish your purpose by locking the rows of interest using [locking reads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) with `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.  When you hit an error and roll back the transaction, the rows are unlocked automatically.

I wrote about this in detail in [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623967/handeling-latency-in-mysql-transactions/18625767#18625767) where the question involved avoiding conflicting inserts but the underlying concept is the same whether you know the row you want already exists, or whether it might or might not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using transactions with a try-catch block?  See this:

```
BEGIN TRAN
SAVE TRAN S1 -- Savepoint so any rollbacks will only affect this transaction

BEGIN TRY
    /* Do your work in here */
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN S1 -- rollback just this transaction
    SET @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    SET @Severity = ERROR_SEVERITY()
    SET @State = ERROR_STATE()
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @Severity, @State) -- re-throw error if needed
END CATCH
```

Comment: I just saw that this was for MySQL, right?  I'm not sure about MySQL; this is for T-SQL.

Comment: It's just MySQL, but there's transactions there. But transactions wouldn't lock the table from other writes, correct? I believe I need to lock the table.