# Locking Mysql Transaction

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, transactions, locking, innodb

We have a table (say, child) that has a relation to another table (say, parent). In a perfect world, it will always have a parent row, and sometimes a child row. It should never have more than one child row, but it may in the future (so a Unique index is not suitable long-term).

Right now, we use transactions and lock the rows. However, because Mysql locks the rows based to the point in time in which it starts, each transaction (if one starts before the other commits) is able to create their own row. Then, on insert, each insert takes effect and we end up with two rows. I think each row is locking its own row, and without committing, it is hidden to the other thread. Basically, transactions have a chicken and egg type of problem.

How can we enforce a policy of up to one row? We can add a unique index and at the time the transaction commits, it will fail. But then we remove the ability to add multiple rows in the future (when one parent would have two child's), which is problematic.

This has to be solved somehow. I just don't know how personally.

**Edit 1: Updated Schema information (I'm using a job schema to represent the problem)**

Table: job (the "Parent")
job_id
job_title
job_payment

Table: job_asignment (the "Child")
job_id
user_id (assigned worker)
est_hours
opt_insurance

Our application is a SaaS-based product that helps manage workflows. We check whether everything necessary is okay before hand (like whether the job is still in the right status, whether the person trying to accept the job was given access, and so on). Then, if that is true, we assign him (insert or update the row in the job_assignment table).

Our problem is that our system takes 2 to 3 seconds for the rest of the assignment to happen (place payment holds, insert the actual row, email the worker that they are assigned, move the status to assigned, and so on). During this time, another user also tries to accept the job, his thread validates everything before (where we check if its still available), and it is. We then start the process on him too, since each thread is a transaction and the changes haven't been committed.

Then, we get two assignment rows. For us, thats bad right now since we only pay one worker.

We would use application locking with temp files or something, but were on a load balanced (HA) environment and cannot guarantee that both users hit the same server.

This seems really rudimentary, but I can't figure out how to solve it. Other than a unique index, the only other way is to highly invest in hardware for the DB and get that window as small as we can.

Does this clarify anything?

Comment: Could you clarify a little more what these transactions look like? It seems that you have a fundamental problem with your data schema - in particular how you address a "child". Show a simple table and query (as simple as possible to demonstrate the problem). Not only will it make it easier to help you but it will force you to think clearly about the problem and you might solve it yourself...

Comment: Why can't you enforce the "one child" rule at the application level? Doing this in the database seems like the wrong place.

Comment: I've added the requested information. Hopefully now you can see the problem with locking in Mysql. From what I can see, it takes the stance of Oracle where the query is from the snapshot of the beginning of the transaction, being good in most cases. However, since the transaction is not committed, the other threads cannot see the other threads changes. Then, we get two or even three rows.

Comment: You need to lock out the job with an application flag when you begin processing. If for some reason processing fails, you would then clear this flag. This way you eliminate the gap in which another user can take the job when it technically isnt available.

Comment: MySQL should be able to handle this condition easily with intention-shared locks using `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` on the row you're *going to* insert: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623967/handeling-latency-in-mysql-transactions/18625767#18625767

Comment: @datasage The application exists in a load-balanced environment, and we don't really feel we can lock the process down. We wouldn't want to limit the number of assignments that can happen at once, since we have thousands that happen every day (and the majority in peak hours). If you have recommendations, I'm happy to listen though.

Comment: @Michael, will the lock work without the unique constraint on the column? Or does it have to have the unique constraint to work?

Comment: No, there only has to be an index so that the index rows or index gap where the rows would be can be exclusively locked by the transaction. The example code didn't have a unique index.