# Is it possible to keep SELECT... FOR UPDATE row-lock after commit?

Tags: java, mysql, locking

I have a SELECT statement that I would like to use to lock the selected row for `ResultSet`-updates.  In particular,

```
stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT name, in_use, done FROM test LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;", ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
if ( rs != null && rs.last() ) {
    name = rs.getString(1);
    System.out.println(name);

    Thread.sleep(60_000);
    // --- Is it possible to keep the row-lock here? ---

    rs.updateInt(2, 1);
    rs.updateRow();
}
```

I realized that I can do any kind of change to the selected row during the 1 minute sleep-period.  Any hints of how to keep the row locked until I close the `ResultSet` would be appreciated.

Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: The question says "after commit," but I don't see a commit happening here... also not sure why you'd want to lock a row for an entire minute.  Usually you want to release them as quickly as possible.

Comment: It is set to auto-commit; so `executeQuery` does the commit.  The `Thread.sleep(60_000)` is just an example;  I do not intend to lock it for a minute without doing anything with it.  One minute gives me enough time to try updating the row this thread is operating on in another connection.  Unfortunately the row is not locked during that minute and this is what I am trying to change...

Comment: The first thing you need to understand, in that case, is that the purpose of a row lock is to prevent *any other session/connection/thread* from modifying that row... so, what you are trying will never work.  The thread doing the work needs to hold the lock in its session, and needs to use proper transactions.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Michael-sqlbot.  I am sorry, but I do not completely understand your answer.  I am aware of the fact that I could manually handle the commit.  However, that would not eliminate the problem I have:  I would like to read one row from the DB, lock that row, do some computations which take a couple of seconds, and then write something back to that one row.  While working on that row, I would like it locked.  Thanks a lot again.

Comment: What I'm trying to explain is that (1) to use row locks, you have to `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` or disable autocommit, and (2) when a row is locked, *only* the MySQL connection (also known as session or thread, in MySQL terminology) that locked the row can modify it.  You can't lock a row "here" (connection 1) and modify it "there" (connection 2).

Comment: Thank you very much, I see what you mean now.  I was actually _not_ trying to change the row from a different session;  all I did was to test whether the row was still locked during the 60 second period or not -- and it was not.  Do I understand you correctly, that doing a SELECT… FOR UPDATE is not enough to lock a row until closing the statement.  If this is the case, is it possible to start a transaction, select a row, lock it, read from it [and do some computations in Java], modify it and then end the transaction and release the lock?

Comment: `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` **does** lock the row until the transaction commits, but as you noticed, the commit is immediate if you are in autocommit mode.  When successful, a second connection using ` SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` will suspend until the lock is released.

Comment: You can also lock a "gap" -- the place where a row would go if it existed, preventing someone else from inserting it, by issuing a query that would have found the row if it had been there, using `FOR UPDATE`.  Shown [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18625767/1695906). The behavior is similar, so that answer might be useful to your understanding.  Testing with the CLI is recommended.

Comment: Very cool, @Michael-sqlbot, I didn't know about locking the "gap".  I modified my code and `setAutoCommit` `false`.  However, this still does not solve the issue:  in my table, I would love to alter `in_use` after querying the row, commit those changes (this works now perfectly), and then at a later point (let's say about 15 seconds of computations later) alter `done`.  I wish to alter `done` only after the computations successfully finished.  After I manually commit the changes to `in_use` now, the lock on my row gets lifted.  Is there no way to just keep a lock on a row even after commits?

Comment: No, there isn't.  You have to do it all in one transaction, as row locks are a function of transactions.  The same code that is doing the "calculations" should be selecting for update, modifying the row, doing the calculations, modifying again, commit.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot so you're leaving a connection open the entire time you perform your "calculations". Is this a drain on your connection pool? Can this cause any issues other than occupying a connection? I guess then you're supposed to limit use of this functionality to as little as possible, right?