# MySQL reading staled data from slaves

Tags: mysql, web-services, race-condition, database-replication, master-slave

I have web application, an Order service that takes orders from customer, and it would first write to MySQL Order table and then creates an event and put it on message queue, and later this event get picked up by a processor, which basically does a lot of stuffs such as send email confirmation, schedule a payment, and prepare for the order something like that, and then it would update the status from this Order table.

So the problem I have is when the customer wants to cancel the order at some point after he/she placed an order. the Order service would first pick up that request and check to see the status of that particular order is determined if the cancellation can be done (if the order is already out on its way to the receiver, then obviously you can't cancel it), but since it reads from Slave but not Master, so there's this little window of staleness that could happen that it reads in as "Preparing", but the actual status is already changed to "Out of delivery". I am wondering what would be alternative other than always read from Master in order to avoid this?

```
[Order service]  ---> [DB] <-----
      |                         |
      |                         |
      v                         |
     [MQ]                       | update status
      ^                         |
      |                         |
      |____[Order processor]____|
```

Comment: Read from the slave for as long as you can, then switch to the master when you must.  "Your order has already shipped" can easily be handled without the master; however, the earlier conditions require not only the master, but really, a transaction and an exclusive row lock on the master, if you want to avoid race conditions where the order ships while being canceled.  The message queue needs to use transactions and exclusive row locks also so that it can't ship while canceling.  I see no way of avoiding an interaction with the master and I suspect you may have other edge cases. Thoughts?

Comment: If you need live data, you obviously have to access the master server (e.g. use a seperate connection for that query or federated tables, which both should not be a big problem). But in most cases, this is more a processing problem than a database problem. A packet usually is not suddenly unavailable because you set a field, it's not a realtime problem. It is oftentimes just a matter of cost to retrieve it (e.g. time/cost to send someone to packaging to sort it out) compared to cost of not doing it (e.g. if you have to pay for retoures in your country or cannot reuse shipped goods). Assume ...

Comment: ... your slave updates every 5 minutes. If e.g. the last possibility to cancel shipment would be if you load it into the courrier truck, you usually know when the truck arrives, so say: no cancellation after 5pm if the status was `packing` at 4:55pm. Maybe you say: after it leaves quality check, it would be too expensive to cancel it, so add the status "start qualitycheck" with a timestamp. If the scan was 5 minutes before (or e.g. 15 minutes after `packed it`), no cancellation possible. Or use the realtime access (maybe only if the last status indicates it is possible it is shipped).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot does row lock work if all rows are immutable, meaning we would create a new row with the new status instead altering for that order.

Comment: @Solarflare these are very good and solid. just wondering can i still use MQ to achieve transaction? or it doesn't make sense to have a MQ

Comment: Yes, with gap locks.  Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18625767/1695906